# Gnuplot: how to plot max and /or min value

Tags: max, gnuplot, minimum

How can I show the max. and/or the min. value(s) of of a graph in a plot at their appropriate position automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this "semi-automatically" using the `stats` command. This command can extract some statistical values from a data set, but requires some reworking:

1. Extract the minimum and maximum y-values, assuming that your data file has two columns, the x-value in the first, the y-values in the second column

   ```
   stats 'file.dat' using 2 nooutput name 'Y_'
   ```

   This gives you the min/max y-values in the variables `Y_min` and `Y_max`, but not the corresponding x-value.
2. The previous step gives you only get the respective indices, which requires you to run `stats` again in order to get the x-values:

   ```
    stats 'file.dat' using 1 every ::Y_index_min::Y_index_min nooutput
    X_min = STATS_min
    stats 'file.dat' using 1 every ::Y_index_max::Y_index_max nooutput
    X_max = STATS_max
   ```
3. Set labels and/or points at the respective coordinates

   ```
   set label 1 sprintf("%.2f", Y_min) center at first X_min,Y_min point pt 7 ps 1 offset 0,-1.5
   set label 2 sprintf("%.2f", Y_max) center at first X_max,Y_max point pt 7 ps 1 offset 0,1.5
   ...
   plot ...
   ```

Comment: Looks nice. Doesn't work if x series is time data though. "Stats command not available in timedata mode"

Comment: @gaoithe Yes, I know. For time data you must do something like `stats 'file.dat' using 2 nooutput name 'Y_'; set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'; stats 'file.dat' using (timecolumn(1)) every ::Y_index_min::Y_index_min noutput; ...; set xdata time; plot ...`

Comment: yes, thank you. I found your answer over here helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977086/plotting-only-the-common-data-in-a-data-series-with-gnuplot  My solution more complicated as was using whitespace-field-seperated file. With date/time inside quotes with whitespace inside that string too. Had to convert to .csv. stats command very useful!

Comment: @gaoithe You don't need csv, ``timecolumn` handles white-space separated date/time fields correctly.

Comment: gnuplot 5.2: Stats command not available in polar mode