# Pass GNUplot variable to system(/usr/bin/awk)

Tags: awk, gnuplot

This command works well in a GNUplot script to find the line in a file with the value -1.98

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/-1.98/{print $2 $1}' /path/to/myfile.txt")
```

Given the GNUplot variable **STATS_min_y** resulting from a plot command, how would I pass **STATS_min_y** into that system() call in place of the -1.98 value?

```
system("/usr/bin/awk '/STATS_min_y/{print $2 $1}' /path/to/myfile.txt")
```

and similar variants fail with a demand for a missing parenthesis.

Comment: You probably want something like `system("/usr/bin/awk -v value=-1.98 '$0 ~ value {print $2 $1}' /path/to/myfile.txt")`

Comment: Using whatever string concatenation support GNUplot has to construct that command string.

Comment: The concat operator for GNUplot is the period, and this works `system("/usr/bin/awk -v value= ". lowValue . " '$0 ~ value {print $2 $1}' /path/to/myfile.txt")` in the sense that it recognizes the value of the variable (lowValue) but fails with this error:  `unknown option -1.98 ignored`, and returns every line of the file.

Comment: There must be no space after `value=`.

Comment: Not sure if my guess is right: [Gnuplot: how to plot max and /or min value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30130639/2604213)

Comment: I'm using GNUplot's STATS_min_y variable to find the lowest value in a file and then need to extract other values from that line. `lowValue = sprintf (" %g", STATS_min_y);`gives me that number in a format I can use, and the command `system("/usr/bin/awk -v value=". lowValue." '$0 ~ value {print $2 $1}' /path/to/myfile.txt")` recognizes the value of the variable but still throws that error about `unknown option`which I guess must mean I have the awk formatting wrong. Though that is odd as the command works properly if the value itself (-1.98) is used as suggested by @fedorqui

Comment: Update: the culprit is the %g format specifier, which is passing a number not a string, to awk. Changed to `lowValue = sprintf (" %s", STATS_min_y);` and all works as expected.

Comment: have you checked the variable STATS_pos_min_y? I guess it might already contain the value you're after.

Comment: @karl I had missed that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the result from `sprintf` directly to `system`. For example:

```
a = system( sprintf("awk '/%g/{print $2,$1}' myfile.txt", STATS_min_y) )
```