# Gnuplot : How to find the x-coordinate corresponding to maximum y value from a multi-column data file?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot file `plot.gp` whose contents are:

```
set terminal epslatex
set output 'data_plot.tex'
set multiplot

stats "data_file_1.dat" u 4 name "A"
stats "data_file_2.dat" u 4 name "B"

plot 'data_file_1.dat' u ($1<A_pos_max_y ? $1+10-A_pos_max_y : $1-A_pos_max_y):4 w p lt rgb "red",
'data_file_2.dat' u ($1<A_pos_max_y ? $1+10-A_pos_max_y : $1-A_pos_max_y):4 w p lt rgb "green"
```

`data_file_1.dat` and `data_file_2.dat` are both data files with 10 rows and 5 columns. The contents are (respectively):

```
#1  2   3   4   5
1   1   1   2   1
2   1   1   4   1
3   1   1   6   1
4   1   1   8   1
5   1   1   16  1
6   1   1   9   1
7   1   1   7   1
8   1   1   5   1
9   1   1   3   1
10  1   1   2   1
```

and

```
#1  2   3   4   5
1   1   1   5   1
2   1   1   7   1
3   1   1   12  1
4   1   1   18  1
5   1   1   9   1
6   1   1   5   1
7   1   1   7   1
8   1   1   3   1
9   1   1   2   1
10  1   1   1   1
```

I need the x coordinate (column 1) corresponding to maximum y value (from column 4). gnuplot displays an error message

```
undefined variable: A_pos_max_y
```

Is there some other way to fine the corresponding x coordinate for maximum y value?

Comment: After the first `stats` command use a `show variables A_` to show all variables which were set from this call. You'll see, that the variable is called `A_index_max`. Note, that this index is zero-based, whereas your values in the first column start at one. How to generally get the matching x-value of the maximum, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30132038/2604213.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you so much! This worked.

Comment: @Christoph Because I am shifting my x axis, the y points on the two ends are joined by a long line, like this - http://imgur.com/a/bvIR7
Is there a way to tell gnuplot to break this line?

Comment: You must draw the two line parts separately. If you have problems with this, please ask a new question. It is difficult to explain this in a comment